# Adding multiple tooltips with forEach function not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So I know a workaround this problem, but In hope to learn more about JavaScript functionality I will present it here so maybe someone can explain to me why this is not working.

```
 <li>
        <a href="#" class="kooltip" data-message="Početna">
          <i class="fas fa-home nav__link" ></i>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="kooltip" data-message="O nama" >
          <i class="fas fa-address-card nav__link" ></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="kooltip" data-message="Usluge">
          <i class="fas fa-notes-medical nav__link" ></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="kooltip" data-message="Kontakt" >
          <i class="fas fa-mail-bulk nav__link" ></i>
        </a>
      </li>





class Tooltip {
    constructor(element){
        this.element = element
        this.message= element.getAttribute("data-message")
    }
    init() {
        const tip = document.createElement("div")
        tip.classList.add("tip")
        tip.textContent = this.message
        this.element.appendChild(tip)

        this.element.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
            tip.classList.add("active")
        })
        this.element.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
            tip.classList.remove("active")
        })

    }
}


const addTooltips = () => {
    const kooltip = document.querySelectorAll(".kooltip")
    kooltip.forEach(tip => {
       new Tooltip(tip)  
        tip.init()
    }) 
}

addTooltips()
```

I want to add tooltip for each of the a tag in the html, but for some reason this is not working and I have no error messages to get info on why not.

Comment: When is `addTooltips()` called? If it is before the elements exist (eg before window onload event) `querySelectorAll(".kooltip")` will return an empty list since they dont exist yet

Comment: It returns NodeList. I also forgot to put "tip.init()" in addTooltips funcition, but even with that it does not work.

Comment: But does it return a filled nodelist or an empty one?. More than likely it isnt filled because you are calling it too early

Comment: No it is not that. It has items in it.

Comment: Ok so what exactly isnt working? Are the tip `<div>`s not getting added to the `<a>` elements, or is the `active` class not being added/removed to the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is inside of `addTooltips`, here's an improved version:

```js
const addTooltips = () => {
  const kooltips = document.querySelectorAll('a.kooltip')

  kooltips.forEach(kooltip => {
    const tip = new Tooltip(kooltip)
    tip.init()
  })
}
addTooltips()
```

Here's a working example:

```js
class Tooltip {
  constructor(element){
    this.element = element
    this.message= element.getAttribute("data-message")
  }
  
  init() {
    const tip = document.createElement("div")
    tip.classList.add("tip")
    tip.textContent = this.message
    this.element.appendChild(tip)

    this.element.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
        tip.classList.add("active")
    })
    this.element.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        tip.classList.remove("active")
    })
  }
}

const addTooltips = () => {
  const kooltips = document.querySelectorAll('a.kooltip')
  
  kooltips.forEach(kt => {
    const tip = new Tooltip(kt)
    tip.init()
  })
}

addTooltips()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="kooltip" data-message="Početna">
      <i class="fas fa-home nav__link" ></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="kooltip" data-message="O nama" >
      <i class="fas fa-address-card nav__link" ></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="kooltip" data-message="Usluge">
      <i class="fas fa-notes-medical nav__link" ></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="kooltip" data-message="Kontakt" >
      <i class="fas fa-mail-bulk nav__link" ></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working like a charm. Could you also tell me when should i query elements with tagname in front of the class name ? Why did you do that in this example ?

Comment: It looks like it will work both ways, with `.kooltip` and `a.kooltip`. When I looked at the `MDN` docs they used `element.className`, I guess to be more explicit. MDN docs say "string must be a valid CSS selector string", so the way you did it initially is also good. Ultimately, it looks like the issue was with you calling `tip.init()` but since `tip` (actual DOM element) did not have a `init` method (your class does), it wasn't doing anything.